# Word addin - Table Bindings not working recently

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

We have a word addin, that has been working for more than 2 years and quite recently (maybe a month or so ago), it has stopped working when binding table entries using the addFromNamedItemSync.

This still works on Microsoft Word for Mac, but doesnt work on Office 365 Online or Microsoft Word for Microsoft 365 MSO.

This is how we are trying to do the binding.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < tables.items.length; i++) {
       contentControl = tables.items[i].insertContentControl();
       contentControl.title = `Table-${ i + 1 }`;
    }
    return context.sync().then(() => {
       for (let i = 1; i <= tables.items.length; i++) {
          Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(
               `Table-${i}`, 
               Office.BindingType.Table, 
               {}, 
               (asyncResult) => {
                  if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                      console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
                  } else {
                      asyncResult.value.addHandlerAsync(
                            Office.EventType.BindingSelectionChanged,
                            selectionHandler, 
                            (asyncR) => {}
                      );
                  }
              });
          }
     });
```

This code works perfectly on MS word on Mac and the bindings are created properly but not on the other platforms.

On the other platforms (Online and Microsoft Word for Microsoft 365 MSO), we get a Error with message as `The specified data object is not compatible with the binding type.` with Code as 2008.

I have tried updating my Office JS versions to the latest to see if it would get resolved but that doenst seem to help either.

Can someone help if there are any changes needed in the latest word addin or if we are making any errors .

OfficeJS Addin Version: 1.1.38 but also tried 1.1.86
OfficeJS helpers Version: 1.0.2

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest posting this to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues

Comment: Thanks, posted to the issues board in Github